# How to take input from user for dictionary in nested json when converting it to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have 2 json files which consists of nested json in it. The general format of these files are:

**JSON1**

```
{
   "apple": {
     "price": {
     "type": "good",
     "value": 82.0,
    }
   },
  "banana": {
    "price": {
    "type": "good",
    "value": 74.0,
    }
   }
 }
```

**JSON2**

```
{
   "apple": {
     "price": {
     "type": "good",
     "value": 45.0,
    }
   },
  "banana": {
    "price": {
    "type": "good",
    "value": 76.0,
    }
   }
 }
```

I wanted to convert them into a dataframe, for which my approach was:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('JSON1.json','r') as f1:
    item1 = json.load(f1)
with open('JSON2.json','r') as f1:
    item2 = json.load(f1)
v1s = [item1['apple']['price']['value'], item1['banana']['price']['value']]
v2s = [item2['apple']['price']['value'], item2['banana']['price']['value']]
index = ['apple', 'banana']

pd.DataFrame({'value1': v1s, 'value2': v2s, 'key': index}).set_index('key')
```

Now, I want that the user must be able to give the input for the place of price stated in the dictionary. For example:  it should ask the user to enter the requirement, and if the user enters taste, then the result should be given for the taste instead of price.

Different json logs will be read which contain taste in place of price

Lastly, the user must be asked what they want in the place of price.

Comment: Why not combine all json? At least the two examples for banana and apple? and then you just have to get the user input like `input()`and then switch / if else, open the desired file.

Comment: Can't combine the json files

Comment: I have updated your json file. I think you can check out with your code.

Comment: Can you please share, how the output looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

def getDF(path,key):
    with open(path[0]+'.json','r') as f1:
        item1 = json.load(f1)
    with open(path[1]+'.json','r') as f1:
        item2 = json.load(f1)
    v1s = [item1['apple'][key]['value'], item1['banana'][key]['value']]
    v2s = [item2['apple'][key]['value'], item2['banana'][key]['value']]
    index = ['apple', 'banana']

    pd.DataFrame({'value1': v1s, 'value2': v2s, 'key': index}).set_index('key')

    
keyPath = {
    "taste": ["JSON2Taste","JSON2Taste"],
    "price": ["JSON1","JSON2"]
}

print("enter the requirement")
userInput = input()

if userInput in keyPath:
    getDF(keyPath[userInput], userInput)
else:
    print("false key")
```

But this is not a elegant solution. It would be easier if you would combine all json in one file and / or at least your two example files.

Comment: the thing is, it's not confined to price or taste , the user can give any value in that place according to what is being mentioned in the json logs

Comment: then you just have to enter a new entry into the key path dict. And again, if you have everything in one file, you could just check the input against the real data and return it

Comment: Actually, I want that user should be giving this input in a command prompt instead of modifying in the code itself

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly should the user give as an input? If you have the json in multiple files, you always need to hard code, at least some parts, of the path for a given condition. Can you explain why you can't put all json in one file?